# Does the ITelemetryChennel with the ServerTelemetryChannel concept exist in the Azure Application Insights Analytics SDK for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, telemetry

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342940/is-it-possible-to-use-logs-to-report-to-azure-application-insights-at-specific-t), regarding Azure Application Insights Analytics,  it answered a concern about managing the log(s) output and associated Azure communication of those logs or "telemetry" back to the Azure cloud service.

However, the `ServerTelemetryChannel` existing from the class `ITelemetryChannel` doesn't seem to be apart of the nodejs sdk.

The question becomes, is that ability therefore not apart of the node sdk?  If so, is there a workaround for similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/develop/Library/Sender.ts#L71), it looks like there is an option to have retries on locally saved telemetry in AI node.js SDK:

```
public setDiskRetryMode(value: boolean, resendInterval?: number, maxBytesOnDisk?: number) {
```

This option seems to be [on by default](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/148052ebaef115cecc0bd8b3f92056ee111431fb/applicationinsights.ts#L41):

```
let _isDiskRetry = true;
```